# Google Apps Script: Getting parameters of url without doGet(e)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently using Apps Script to build a webpage. Is there a way to get the parameters in the URL without using doGet(e)? i.e. Can I use a getParams() function to retrieve the URL?

Comment: If you don't have a `doGet` function, then you don't have a web app that can respond to an http GET request. In other words, your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*No, it is not possible*

### How [Web-Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) work

> When a user visits an app or a program sends the app an HTTP GET request, Apps Script runs the function doGet(e). When a program sends the app an HTTP POST request, Apps Script runs doPost(e) instead. In both cases, the e argument represents an event parameter that can contain information about any request parameters.

### Ask for a feature request

Google has a tool called [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) that tracks bugs and feature requests during product development. You can open a new feature request there.